# Tracker-miner error ubuntu 18.04

Tags: syslog

After booting and logging in I get an error message as soon as desktop is visible, message appearing in a dialogue.
[image]
When pressing "report error", the box closes without any further action.
In syslog I see

```
tracker-miner-f[2535]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 4 (file:///home/mue/Schreibtisch) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url
```

"Schreibtisch" means "Desktop" but this standard folder is existing.
Tracker version is 2.0.3.

After performing `tracker reset --hard` and `sudo reboot` I get the following in `syslog`

```
gnome-software[2644]: Failed to find one package for tracker.desktop, /usr/share/applications/tracker.desktop
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version and which `tracker --version` ?

Comment: After booting: you mean, after having logged in? You see the error message in the console or in a graphical dialog? Please describe a little more, use "edit".

Comment: @pLumo Post is edited.

Comment: @vanadium Post is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may indicate an issue with the tracker database. You may resolve this by having Tracker recreate the database.

```
tracker reset --hard
sudo reboot
```

The  `reset --hard` command will kill all running processes and remove the database. On an next reboot, the tracker services will resume as if tracker was just installed.

This normally should not happen. However, some incident may have caused the issue, e.g. as a result of an improper shutdown or an unexpected crash of one of the processes. This problem, normally, should not regularly return.

Comment: After this a different error of tracker is occuring. I have edited the post. Is it worth installing `tracker-extract`?

Comment: Did it resolve your current issue?